# How to set the coordinate for my button in JavaFX?

Tags: java, button, javafx

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    ScrollBar sc = new ScrollBar();
    sc.setMin(0);
    sc.setMax(100);

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.relocate(150, 100);
    btn.setText("Launch Keyboard lights");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    root.getChildren().add(btn);
    root.getChildren().add(sc);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

I tried using btn.setXlayout and y and it also didn't work. I think its because of the root of (new Scene(root, 200, 250)); but what am I supposed to write to get the button into a new position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `StackPane` is probably not what you want here - it is used to stack controls on top of one another (z-axis), but the controls themselves are positioned according to the `Alignment` property of the `StackPane`.

You are probably looking for something like `AnchorPane`, which allows you to anchor controls to one or more sides of the pane. Alternatively, you can use one of the many other layout panes available in JavaFX, depending on what layout you are looking to achieve.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) to get an idea of the various layout panes available. Also, you may want to play around with [Scene Builder](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/) at least for prototyping.

Answer (score 2):

A `StackPane` is a [layout pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102), which means it organizes the layout of its child nodes for you. (By default it centers them, though you can change that so that it positions them in any of the alignments specified by [`Pos`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Pos.html).)

The recommendation is that you use a layout pane, or combination of layout panes, that manage the child nodes in the way you want. If you really want to position them yourself (really, you don't), you can use a `Pane` as the root instead of a `StackPane`, and then use `btn.setLayoutX` and `btn.setLayoutY(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.deneme
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class MainApp extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
            ScrollBar sc = new ScrollBar();
            sc.setMin(0);
            sc.setMax(100);
            Pane pane = new Pane();
            Button btn = new Button();
            pane.setPrefSize(300,250);



            btn.setText("Launch Keyboard lights");
            btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("asda");

                }
            });

            StackPane root = new StackPane();
            pane.getChildren().add(btn);
            pane.getChildren().add(sc);
            btn.setLayoutX(50);  //this is how you change locations
            btn.setLayoutY(50);  //this is how you change locations
            root.getChildren().add(pane);

            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```